# How to position buttons in row or column depending on text lenght in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to solve this issue: AlertDialog has two buttons in a row, but if the text is too long it's either cut or eclipsed. These options don't fit me. Therefore, I'm trying to find a dynamic way, so it works like this: if the width doesn't match parent, then put it in a column.
But the problem is that I don't know the button's size when deciding column or row. Hardcodning some min length is also wrong.

How I'm trying:

```
@Composable
fun TwoButtons(buttonText1: String, buttonText2: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Row(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ) {
        TextButton(onClick = { /* todo */ }) {
            Text(text = buttonText1)
        }
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ) {
        TextButton(onClick = { /* todo */ }) {
            Text(text = buttonText2)
        }
    }
}
```

}

But it doesn't work.
Is there any way to know the size of these buttons before deciding column/row? or maybe there's a better approach to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jetpack compose - foundation 1.4.0 they introduced
`FlowRow` and `FlowColumn` as @ExperimentalFoundationApi that allow for a more flexible row and column based layout of components that will break to a new line if there is not enough space on the main axis.

update following dependeny to the latest version

> implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.0"

the TwoButtons Composable could be change into

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun TwoButtons(buttonText1: String, buttonText2: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    FlowRow(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp, 12.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
    ) {
        TextButton(onClick = { /* todo */ }) {
            Text(text = buttonText1)
        }
        TextButton(onClick = { /* todo */ }) {
            Text(text = buttonText2)
        }
    }
}
```